# How to use pip install python packages locally like npm does

Tags: python, path, pip, npm, package-managers

Say I have a project named `Foo`, and and want to install `requests` package locally for this project. What I am expecting is some structure similar to this:

`Foo/`
`|-main.py`
`|-requirements.txt`
`|-README.md`
`|-python_modules/`
`|-|-requests`
`...`

And I can do this by `pip install -r requirments.txt -t ./python_modules/`, however, this doesn't work properly because there are no `__init__.py` under `python_modules/` so programs won't automatically import every packages in `python_modules`.

On the other hand, `npm install` does this very well.

So my question is, how to let `pip` work the same as `npm` does?

PS: I know there are other conventions using `virtualenv` or `pythonbrew`, but I still want to ask this question.

Comment: `virtualenv`. Python does not have this possibility by default.

Comment: it would work if you added the `python_modules` directory to `sys.path` in your main.

Comment: As @mata said, you can change `sys.path` or just export `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Like: `$ export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/python_modules` and you are set

Comment: Unfortunately, that $PWD is set when you run the command, so you can't simply do this in a dotfile and adopt it as a convention that "just works" for all of your projects. I suppose you could create a bootstrap script but it would be nice if this was transparent.

Comment: But you can add the string `./python_modules` to the `PYTHONPATH` variable, so that when you run `python` from the project's root folder it will reference the local `python_modules` folder. This cross-project solution works for me on Linux, Windows and Mac.

Comment: @ehremo please add an answer with this info, so I can upvote :D

Comment: @Koobz if you wanted to put the export mentioned you could always set it in `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this problem in the Python world is to use virtualenvs or, even better, a wrapper like pipenv. If you install pipenv, you should be able to create a new virtualenv with a simple `pipenv install`:

```
[user@host Foo]$ pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this
project… ⠋Using base prefix '/usr' New python executable in
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/Foo-oXnKEj-P/bin/python3 Also
creating executable in
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/Foo-oXnKEj-P/bin/python Installing
setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/Foo-oXnKEj-P
Creating a Pipfile for this project… Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies… Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (c23e27)!  Installing dependencies from
Pipfile.lock (c23e27)… �� ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 —
00:00:00 To activate this project's virtualenv, run the following: $
pipenv shell
```

Then enter the virtualenv with `pipenv shell`

```
[user@host Foo]$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell
(/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave. source
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/Foo-oXnKEj-P/bin/activate

[user@host Foo]$ source /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/Foo-oXnKEj-P/bin/activate
```

Finally, you can install the packages in your requirements.txt:

```
(Foo-oXnKEj-P) [user@host Foo]$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Django==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) Using
cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/f9/94c20658f0cdecc2b6607811e2c0bb042408a51f589e5ad0cb0eac3236a1/Django-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from Django==2.0.4->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django Successfully installed
Django-2.0.4 pytz-2018.4

(Foo-oXnKEj-P) [user@host Foo]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/) with local poetry.toml config

```
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has been first asked, there has been some movement in that direction. A *Python enhancement proposal* has been made to suggest such a feature: [PEP 582 "*Python local packages directory*"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0582/). It is still a draft though, but...

There are some tools that already implement this *PEP*. The most advanced that I know of is [*PDM - Python Development Master*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/). Another one is [*Pyflow*](https://pypi.org/project/pyflow/).

I believe both (in particular *pdm*) would offer a UX similar to *npm* and its `node_modules`.

Some other mentions:

- [*pythonloc*](https://pypi.org/project/pythonloc/)
- [*importation*](https://pypi.org/project/importation/)